# ASP.NET MVC 3 Authentication with cookie less sessions

Tags: session, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3, sessionid

I need to implement a simple secure area on a MVC 3 website. I can not use cookies and can not pass session ID in the URL. Are there any other implemented options in ASP.NET?

P.S. I know it is possible in other environments.

Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use cookies and don't want to pass anything in the URL (or hidden fields in a POST request) your server simply cannot distinguish the users. Don't forget that HTTP is a stateless protocol. You could implement some sort of custom HTTP headers that would be sent along each request and allow you to track users but when you think about it: that's exactly what cookies do, so instead of reinventing the wheel, use cookies :-)

Comment: What about headers or hidden input? PHP does it nicely, but I don't want to use PHP.

Comment: @Arthur, as I said you could use hidden inputs and custom HTTP headers. Nothing built-in ASP.NET though. You will have to implement your own authentication module to handle it.

Comment: So far it looks like headers are the brightest option :( Thank you